when I am logged in my page seems to be proper, but when I am just visiting the page in incognito, some css are not applied & page looks weired
as I mentioned, my page looks proper when I am logged in, and when I am logged out some css in the page doesn't get load as a result tabs & carousel didn't look proper. here is what I have tried,

cleared all the caches
checked on regenerate CSS ...
when tried url with /?nocache , then it looks proper
(xyz.com/?nocache)

when I do some changes & publish, it will seen properly for some time & then it again comes back to improper.
any suggestions would be highly apprecated.

You can avoid caching problems with style sheets by including a version number when you enqueue the file. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/
